# Determinant of a matrix filled with elements of the Thue–Morse sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, determinants, integer-sequences

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose we fill a square matrix $n\times n$ row-by-row with the first $n^2$ elements of the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence#Recurrence_relation) (with indexes from $0$ to $n^2-1$). Let $\mathcal D_n$ be the determinant of this matrix. For example,
$$\small\mathcal D_7=\left| 
\begin{array}{}
 t_0 & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5 & t_6 \\
 t_7 & t_8 & t_9 & t_{10} & t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
 t_{14} & t_{15} & t_{16} & t_{17} & t_{18} & t_{19} & t_{20} \\
 t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} & t_{24} & t_{25} & t_{26} & t_{27} \\
 t_{28} & t_{29} & t_{30} & t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} & t_{34} \\
 t_{35} & t_{36} & t_{37} & t_{38} & t_{39} & t_{40} & t_{41} \\
 t_{42} & t_{43} & t_{44} & t_{45} & t_{46} & t_{47} & t_{48} \\
\end{array}
\right|=\left| 
\begin{array}{}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right|=0.$$
**Question:** For which $n$ does $\mathcal D_n\ne0$ hold?

Using a brute-force computer search I found only $5$ cases: $\mathcal D_2 = -1,\,$ $\mathcal D_{11} = 9,\,$ $\mathcal D_{13} = -9,\,$ $\mathcal D_{19} = 270,\,$ $\mathcal D_{23} = -900,$ and no other cases for $n\le1940$. Are there any other cases except these five?

Comment: Maybe it is better to consider the differnce $n-{\rm rank }\, \mathcal D_n$?

Comment: I guess you can define Thue-Morse matrices using the pattern $\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ B & A\end{pmatrix}$, like the Thue-Morse sequence is defined using the pattern $AB$.

Comment: Experimentally there seems to be a simple formula for the rank of your matrix in the case $n=2^k-1$, which corresponds to the iteration $n \to 2n+1$. Using $n \to 2n$ the rank seems to stabilize. Maybe you can try other iterations.

Comment: There are some orders n for which it is easy to prove the determinant is zero. When n is a large enough power of two, there are duplicated rows (first and fourth) and for n one more than a power of two, the first column is zero. You might see if a parity argument takes care of cases of large even orders, or even composite orders being zero.  Of interest is when the matrices are non singular over F2. Gerhard "Use Power Of Binary Expansion" Paseman, 2018.11.07.

Comment: If $n \geq 4$ is even then the determinant is 0 because  the columns $C_0, C_1,... C_{n-1} $ satisfy $C_{2k}+C_{2k+1}=(1,1,...,1) $ for every $k $.

Comment: Searching the OEIS gives [4 results](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C11%2C13%2C19%2C23&language=english&go=Search) of those [A207039](https://oeis.org/A207039) - "Primes whose binary expansion is not palindromic" seems the most relevant. It would be interesting to try to prove that for composite numbers or non-palindromic binary numbers the determinant is zero. This also suggest the question: does there exists ternary (and higher) analog of the Thue–Morse sequence such that numbers for which determinant is non-zero is subsets of non-palindromic ternary primes?

Comment: Some other variations: 1. Instead of starting with "0" in Thue_Morse start with any other number in any base. 2. Fill a $m \times n$ matrix instead and consider $\sqrt {\det(AA^T)}$ 3. Consider the product of non-zero eigenvalues instead of the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

not an answer just the result of a computation. The following plot shows for each $n$ the minimal number $k$ such that the first $k$ rows are linearly dependent. The question is to find all $n$ such that $k=n+1$.

[image]